# Display showtime and booking links of the particular movies using International Showtime api

Tags: php, curl

I am using International Showtime api and using that I have displayed list of the movies, images and their titles. On click of the image of the particular movie I want to display their showtimes and the booking links.

Below is the code:

```
    <?php
function call_curl($url)
{
    // Get cURL resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    // Set method
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    // Set options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // Set headers
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
      "X-API-Key: gZ1oAJY7Tz82K4S6yZ01mcrHyi9fRp53",
     ]
    );

    // Send the request & save response to $resp
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Book Show</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container" style="border:1px solid">

            <div class="container-fluid">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Book My Show</a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                      <li><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Plays</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Trailers & Video</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <?php
                $movie_url="https://api.internationalshowtimes.com/v4/movies/";
                $movies=call_curl($movie_url);
                $movies_data = array_reduce(json_decode($movies,true), 'array_merge', array());
                foreach($movies_data as $value) 
                {
                    if(!empty($value['poster_image_thumbnail']))
                    {
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-md-2" style="height:300px; width:20%;">

                            <img src="<?php echo $value['poster_image_thumbnail']; ?>" style="height:80%;"/></img>
                        <?php echo $value['title'];?>
                    </div>
                <?php  
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the documentation [here](https://api.internationalshowtimes.com/documentation/v4/), and some suggestions are

Get all showtimes of location and with title, image.. fields:

```
    // Set url
$url1 = "https://api.internationalshowtimes.com/v4/showtimes/?location=12.972442,77.580643";

$showtimes = call_curl($url1);//get all showtimes details
$showtimes = json_decode($showtimes);
foreach ($showtimes as $details) {//Now loop through all showtime
    foreach ($details as $detail) {//get full details of each movie
        $movie['start_at'] = $detail->start_at;
        $movie['booking_type'] = $detail->booking_type;
        $movie['auditorium'] = $detail->auditorium;//add other field similarly
        $movie_id = $detail->movie_id;
        $url2 = "https://api.internationalshowtimes.com/v4/movies/$movie_id/?location=12.972442,77.580643&movie_fields=id,title,slug,poster_image_thumbnail";
        $movie[] = call_curl($url2);
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($movie);//this will have all the movie details with title, image, genre details
echo "</pre>";

function call_curl($url)
{
    // Get cURL resource
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    // Set method
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    // Set options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // Set headers
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
      "X-API-Key: gZ1oAJY7Tz82K4S6yZ01mcrHyi9fRp53",
     ]
    );
    // Send the request & save response to $resp
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    // Close request to clear up some resources
    curl_close($ch);
    /*if(!$resp) {
      die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
    } else {
      //echo "Response HTTP Status Code : " . curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

      //echo "\nResponse HTTP Body : " . $resp;
      echo "<pre>";
      $arr=json_decode($resp,true);
      print_r($arr);
      echo "</pre>";
    }*/
    return $data;

}
```

**OUTPUT:**
Below is for one movie:

```
Array
(
    [start_at] => 2017-06-08T22:00:00+05:30
    [booking_type] => external
    [auditorium] => SCREEN 6
    [0] => {"movie":{"id":"20606","slug":"baywatch","title":"Baywatch","poster_image_thumbnail":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154/6HE4xd8zloDqmjMZuhUCCw2UcY1.jpg","original_title":"Baywatch","original_language":"en","synopsis":"Devoted lifeguard Mitch Buchannon butts heads with a brash new recruit. Together, they uncover a local criminal plot that threatens the future of the Bay.","runtime":116,"genres":[{"id":"0","name":"Action"},{"id":"3","name":"Comedy"}],"poster_image":{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92/6HE4xd8zloDqmjMZuhUCCw2UcY1.jpg","size":{"width":92,"height":138}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154/6HE4xd8zloDqmjMZuhUCCw2UcY1.jpg","size":{"width":154,"height":231}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/6HE4xd8zloDqmjMZuhUCCw2UcY1.jpg","size":{"width":185,"height":278}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/6HE4xd8zloDqmjMZuhUCCw2UcY1.jpg","size":{"width":342,"height":513}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/6HE4xd8zloDqmjMZuhUCCw2UcY1.jpg","size":{"width":500,"height":750}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/6HE4xd8zloDqmjMZuhUCCw2UcY1.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":1170}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/6HE4xd8zloDqmjMZuhUCCw2UcY1.jpg","size":{"width":2000,"height":3000}}]},"scene_images":[{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/tryI7qZHaLMVzMNpLyKHKDiZOLc.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/tryI7qZHaLMVzMNpLyKHKDiZOLc.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/tryI7qZHaLMVzMNpLyKHKDiZOLc.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/tryI7qZHaLMVzMNpLyKHKDiZOLc.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/tryI7qZHaLMVzMNpLyKHKDiZOLc.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/tryI7qZHaLMVzMNpLyKHKDiZOLc.jpg","size":{"width":3840,"height":2160}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/t6TL7V9IsT4Ktx6YO8b1UYj3agd.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/t6TL7V9IsT4Ktx6YO8b1UYj3agd.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/t6TL7V9IsT4Ktx6YO8b1UYj3agd.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/t6TL7V9IsT4Ktx6YO8b1UYj3agd.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/t6TL7V9IsT4Ktx6YO8b1UYj3agd.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/t6TL7V9IsT4Ktx6YO8b1UYj3agd.jpg","size":{"width":3840,"height":2160}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/603wLumdVVXjKLNhf6vP1jXsd3e.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/603wLumdVVXjKLNhf6vP1jXsd3e.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/603wLumdVVXjKLNhf6vP1jXsd3e.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/603wLumdVVXjKLNhf6vP1jXsd3e.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/603wLumdVVXjKLNhf6vP1jXsd3e.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/603wLumdVVXjKLNhf6vP1jXsd3e.jpg","size":{"width":3840,"height":2160}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/t1cq0DBDyIPeQkso23YsOy6q9iU.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/t1cq0DBDyIPeQkso23YsOy6q9iU.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/t1cq0DBDyIPeQkso23YsOy6q9iU.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/t1cq0DBDyIPeQkso23YsOy6q9iU.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/t1cq0DBDyIPeQkso23YsOy6q9iU.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/t1cq0DBDyIPeQkso23YsOy6q9iU.jpg","size":{"width":3840,"height":2160}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/eJ7uvfB0HTnipuB6pUuEFvtrjp6.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/eJ7uvfB0HTnipuB6pUuEFvtrjp6.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/eJ7uvfB0HTnipuB6pUuEFvtrjp6.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/eJ7uvfB0HTnipuB6pUuEFvtrjp6.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/eJ7uvfB0HTnipuB6pUuEFvtrjp6.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/eJ7uvfB0HTnipuB6pUuEFvtrjp6.jpg","size":{"width":3840,"height":2160}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/txDmpGYl4RmZBOAzyfJcibKrTdI.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/txDmpGYl4RmZBOAzyfJcibKrTdI.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/txDmpGYl4RmZBOAzyfJcibKrTdI.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/txDmpGYl4RmZBOAzyfJcibKrTdI.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/txDmpGYl4RmZBOAzyfJcibKrTdI.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/txDmpGYl4RmZBOAzyfJcibKrTdI.jpg","size":{"width":3840,"height":2160}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/rhya0ioZ4ovtAmFC9FNo5UuEg4k.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/rhya0ioZ4ovtAmFC9FNo5UuEg4k.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/rhya0ioZ4ovtAmFC9FNo5UuEg4k.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/rhya0ioZ4ovtAmFC9FNo5UuEg4k.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/rhya0ioZ4ovtAmFC9FNo5UuEg4k.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/rhya0ioZ4ovtAmFC9FNo5UuEg4k.jpg","size":{"width":3840,"height":2160}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/q6ijCw7A1rXMhm2uzNTB8a6OTDh.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/q6ijCw7A1rXMhm2uzNTB8a6OTDh.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/q6ijCw7A1rXMhm2uzNTB8a6OTDh.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/q6ijCw7A1rXMhm2uzNTB8a6OTDh.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/q6ijCw7A1rXMhm2uzNTB8a6OTDh.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/q6ijCw7A1rXMhm2uzNTB8a6OTDh.jpg","size":{"width":3840,"height":2160}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/vZqBnSUwmSwyLHLYYhgtEkS6qAR.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/vZqBnSUwmSwyLHLYYhgtEkS6qAR.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/vZqBnSUwmSwyLHLYYhgtEkS6qAR.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/vZqBnSUwmSwyLHLYYhgtEkS6qAR.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/vZqBnSUwmSwyLHLYYhgtEkS6qAR.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/vZqBnSUwmSwyLHLYYhgtEkS6qAR.jpg","size":{"width":3840,"height":2160}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/5KJp2ZJ1AxP7EmVoKuN2xev8H9R.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/5KJp2ZJ1AxP7EmVoKuN2xev8H9R.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/5KJp2ZJ1AxP7EmVoKuN2xev8H9R.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/5KJp2ZJ1AxP7EmVoKuN2xev8H9R.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/5KJp2ZJ1AxP7EmVoKuN2xev8H9R.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/5KJp2ZJ1AxP7EmVoKuN2xev8H9R.jpg","size":{"width":3840,"height":2160}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/ar5FTwRq9zTgn8HWekIGeToT2cr.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/ar5FTwRq9zTgn8HWekIGeToT2cr.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/ar5FTwRq9zTgn8HWekIGeToT2cr.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/ar5FTwRq9zTgn8HWekIGeToT2cr.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/ar5FTwRq9zTgn8HWekIGeToT2cr.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/ar5FTwRq9zTgn8HWekIGeToT2cr.jpg","size":{"width":3840,"height":2160}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/mOGmp3NgJ4yKJ0RgIB0GffitEM7.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/mOGmp3NgJ4yKJ0RgIB0GffitEM7.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/mOGmp3NgJ4yKJ0RgIB0GffitEM7.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/mOGmp3NgJ4yKJ0RgIB0GffitEM7.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/mOGmp3NgJ4yKJ0RgIB0GffitEM7.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/mOGmp3NgJ4yKJ0RgIB0GffitEM7.jpg","size":{"width":3840,"height":2160}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/zbNnL182Xrnu7CpKpyzwUgbdSZo.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/zbNnL182Xrnu7CpKpyzwUgbdSZo.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/zbNnL182Xrnu7CpKpyzwUgbdSZo.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/zbNnL182Xrnu7CpKpyzwUgbdSZo.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/zbNnL182Xrnu7CpKpyzwUgbdSZo.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/zbNnL182Xrnu7CpKpyzwUgbdSZo.jpg","size":{"width":3840,"height":2160}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/cUHWtD8gxqaz0u23cdoz0TM159O.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/cUHWtD8gxqaz0u23cdoz0TM159O.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/cUHWtD8gxqaz0u23cdoz0TM159O.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/cUHWtD8gxqaz0u23cdoz0TM159O.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/cUHWtD8gxqaz0u23cdoz0TM159O.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/cUHWtD8gxqaz0u23cdoz0TM159O.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/lAE4D3KowfR8nTfHSeLuEYHWjmF.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/lAE4D3KowfR8nTfHSeLuEYHWjmF.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/lAE4D3KowfR8nTfHSeLuEYHWjmF.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/lAE4D3KowfR8nTfHSeLuEYHWjmF.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/lAE4D3KowfR8nTfHSeLuEYHWjmF.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/lAE4D3KowfR8nTfHSeLuEYHWjmF.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/bU78AWJk7LcpKSMUhLV224d4jtk.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/bU78AWJk7LcpKSMUhLV224d4jtk.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/bU78AWJk7LcpKSMUhLV224d4jtk.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/bU78AWJk7LcpKSMUhLV224d4jtk.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/bU78AWJk7LcpKSMUhLV224d4jtk.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/bU78AWJk7LcpKSMUhLV224d4jtk.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/vSY748KlJffgIq4nrzklopU4PEK.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/vSY748KlJffgIq4nrzklopU4PEK.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/vSY748KlJffgIq4nrzklopU4PEK.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/vSY748KlJffgIq4nrzklopU4PEK.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/vSY748KlJffgIq4nrzklopU4PEK.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/vSY748KlJffgIq4nrzklopU4PEK.jpg","size":{"width":3840,"height":2160}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/xICo1Hoa9XItooriqGfIn6bwXRH.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/xICo1Hoa9XItooriqGfIn6bwXRH.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/xICo1Hoa9XItooriqGfIn6bwXRH.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/xICo1Hoa9XItooriqGfIn6bwXRH.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/xICo1Hoa9XItooriqGfIn6bwXRH.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/xICo1Hoa9XItooriqGfIn6bwXRH.jpg","size":{"width":3840,"height":2160}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/tGfAIG1ZMBDExoYkhMRQzPy20oS.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/tGfAIG1ZMBDExoYkhMRQzPy20oS.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/tGfAIG1ZMBDExoYkhMRQzPy20oS.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/tGfAIG1ZMBDExoYkhMRQzPy20oS.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/tGfAIG1ZMBDExoYkhMRQzPy20oS.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/tGfAIG1ZMBDExoYkhMRQzPy20oS.jpg","size":{"width":3840,"height":2160}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/nYO8VdBNUhx6TPEcl5pbmly64NY.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/nYO8VdBNUhx6TPEcl5pbmly64NY.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/nYO8VdBNUhx6TPEcl5pbmly64NY.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/nYO8VdBNUhx6TPEcl5pbmly64NY.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/nYO8VdBNUhx6TPEcl5pbmly64NY.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/nYO8VdBNUhx6TPEcl5pbmly64NY.jpg","size":{"width":3840,"height":2160}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/8ABFP19p5ebnj9wtx1Vx3Hy9xpz.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/8ABFP19p5ebnj9wtx1Vx3Hy9xpz.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/8ABFP19p5ebnj9wtx1Vx3Hy9xpz.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/8ABFP19p5ebnj9wtx1Vx3Hy9xpz.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/8ABFP19p5ebnj9wtx1Vx3Hy9xpz.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/8ABFP19p5ebnj9wtx1Vx3Hy9xpz.jpg","size":{"width":3840,"height":2160}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/jAQow2bvuRt2HPjkuaiTSsHAkfS.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/jAQow2bvuRt2HPjkuaiTSsHAkfS.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/jAQow2bvuRt2HPjkuaiTSsHAkfS.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/jAQow2bvuRt2HPjkuaiTSsHAkfS.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/jAQow2bvuRt2HPjkuaiTSsHAkfS.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/jAQow2bvuRt2HPjkuaiTSsHAkfS.jpg","size":{"width":3840,"height":2160}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/kNvdCvBjKRnYm0rM5yMgOg3JhNr.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/kNvdCvBjKRnYm0rM5yMgOg3JhNr.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/kNvdCvBjKRnYm0rM5yMgOg3JhNr.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/kNvdCvBjKRnYm0rM5yMgOg3JhNr.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/kNvdCvBjKRnYm0rM5yMgOg3JhNr.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/kNvdCvBjKRnYm0rM5yMgOg3JhNr.jpg","size":{"width":3840,"height":2160}}]},{"image_files":[{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/v9TdQleXaveabiuOw9cyUOIUfeb.jpg","size":{"width":300,"height":169}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/v9TdQleXaveabiuOw9cyUOIUfeb.jpg","size":{"width":780,"height":439}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/v9TdQleXaveabiuOw9cyUOIUfeb.jpg","size":{"width":1000,"height":563}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/v9TdQleXaveabiuOw9cyUOIUfeb.jpg","size":{"width":1280,"height":720}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920/v9TdQleXaveabiuOw9cyUOIUfeb.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}},{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/v9TdQleXaveabiuOw9cyUOIUfeb.jpg","size":{"width":1920,"height":1080}}]}],"trailers":[{"language":"en","is_official":true,"trailer_files":[{"format":"youtube","transfert":"1920x1080","url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUFgJ8f9slo"}]},{"language":"en","is_official":true,"trailer_files":[{"format":"youtube","transfert":"1920x1080","url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyKOgnaf0BU"}]}],"ratings":{"imdb":{"value":"6.1","vote_count":648},"tmdb":{"value":5.6,"vote_count":223}},"age_limits":{"DK":"t.o.11","US":"R","BR":"14","DE":12,"GB":"15","RU":"18+","IE":"15A"},"release_dates":{"RU":[{"locale":"ru-RU","region":null,"date":"2017-06-01"}],"DK":[{"locale":"da-DK","region":null,"date":"2017-06-01"}],"CH":[{"locale":"de-CH","region":null,"date":"2017-06-21"}],"US":[{"locale":"en-US","region":null,"date":"2017-05-26"},{"locale":"en-US","region":null,"date":"2017-05-25"}],"BR":[{"locale":"pt-BR","region":null,"date":"2017-06-15"}],"DE":[{"locale":"de-DE","region":null,"date":"2017-06-01"}],"AU":[{"locale":"en-AU","region":null,"date":"2017-06-01"}],"ES":[{"locale":"es-ES","region":null,"date":"2017-06-16"}],"FR":[{"locale":"fr-FR","region":null,"date":"2017-06-21"}],"GB":[{"locale":"en-GB","region":null,"date":"2017-05-29"}],"UA":[{"locale":"uk-UA","region":null,"date":"2017-06-01"}],"IE":[{"locale":"en-IE","region":null,"date":"2017-05-26"}]},"website":"http://www.thebaywatchmovie.com/","production_companies":null,"keywords":null,"imdb_id":"tt1469304","tmdb_id":"339846","rentrak_film_id":125754,"cast":[{"id":"4c934fa80bc4f9271604ca2a577f8ea3","character":"Mitch Buchanan","name":"Dwayne Johnson"},{"id":"ca7e4bad804a48b19a21a461be45abf5","character":"Matt Brody","name":"Zac Efron"},{"id":"b21140d7b14026ff9dd33a5c7e5a3da9","character":"Summer Quinn","name":"Alexandra Daddario"},{"id":"c9f6457dba059e03dea3fed6e32a56ed","character":"C.J. Parker","name":"Kelly Rohrbach"},{"id":"51ae3a92ba49c90bd9b0d48565cba5ee","character":"Victoria Leeds","name":"Priyanka Chopra"},{"id":"0d56f6e48a07824e584ec9de88edae98","character":"Stephanie Holden","name":"Ilfenesh Hadera"},{"id":"64ae6f0d63b0d7cf335f0f52c7c63550","character":"Captain Thorpe","name":"Rob Huebel"},{"id":"396caf2714bec6f965e918d25042e47d","character":"Sgt. Ellerbee","name":"Yahya Abdul-Mateen II"},{"id":"2fb7f0d815969e2e47b8b7d56d3c32c2","character":"Sergeant","name":"John Cenatiempo"},{"id":"49a175399400e222a50fb71471353241","character":"Casey Jean Parker","name":"Pamela Anderson"},{"id":"4eeb78578c73316988110501033f4cfa","character":"Dave the Tech","name":"Hannibal Buress"},{"id":"9fa2f63cff1c166b5b6b57132df1cfa7","character":"Julia","name":"Charlotte McKinney"},{"id":"b7df2fbee8cfad8aee12a8b3375c57c5","character":"Leon","name":"Jack Kesy"},{"id":"33cc7c1b2370463e33997808bb54d8dc","character":"The Mentor","name":"David Hasselhoff"},{"id":"d2a78894055b5a6cfc0f1bb7404262ec","character":"Amber","name":"Izabel Goulart"},{"id":"7054a42ca2fdc4f517dba12e28eab727","character":"Lifeguard","name":"Ana Flavia Gavlak"},{"id":"678c0c1b42b2808cc0a20e905aa0a757","character":"Surfer beach babe","name":"Angelique Kenney"},{"id":"4dcf259368c1f7b069dc2fb890b9ac20","character":"Councilman Rodriguez","name":"Oscar Nunez"},{"id":"28885993f0410cd29ee23cb388b81b23","character":"Ronnie","name":"Jon Bass"},{"id":"7757f858514e3b3f51f32467b70cd977","character":"Skateboarder #1","name":"Brandon Larracuente"},{"id":"bd06c05c98e1d21fe4afda9a4fd0fec1","character":"Bikini Model","name":"Maegan Vogel"},{"id":"738804afd66afd7bdd45b132ce6dbf7a","character":"Allegre","name":"Haviland Stillwell"},{"id":"bd8637f92be6bbc2f7212992b5367c0f","character":"VIP Party Member","name":"Kera Lynn"},{"id":"afaf1a923bc684128940535419571cec","character":"Doctor","name":"Whitney Goin"},{"id":"b26e35f8deb40c70cf879d1720ead920","character":"Frankie","name":"Amin Joseph"},{"id":"d3bae70c9d49bb7cb5a74cdd0eae7fc4","character":"Carmen","name":"Belinda"},{"id":"9a0bf9f19fbe7898e890c9100d52dfd5","character":"Lifeguard","name":"Lee Hodge"},{"id":"caf8e99f1f46061a73f3f6d2844aa59f","character":"The Kitchen Worker","name":"Earl Poitier"},{"id":"6bdf237d8f996a655a1e352e291b63a6","character":"Bikini Girl","name":"Shay Davila"},{"id":"ffd570715ed1561b754a9be1bb6ee75a","character":"Yachter","name":"Barbara Vincent"},{"id":"45b76362dd0830cbdf8006150d1bd5bf","character":"Lifeguard #1","name":"Damon Preston"},{"id":"86c89a9cc077b8f454ae006b9531a5ae","character":"Beach Goer","name":"Bria Danielle Davis"},{"id":"df0897f9c3570ca5d5d5c520fe559889","character":"Crewman","name":"Cody Scott"},{"id":"456821c3be5b6d7c8d60ece7b06ff61d","character":"Interviewer","name":"Samantha Harris"},{"id":"0a6e346c3fb9815eb1cb7ea303d07aff","character":"Helicopter Pilot","name":"Seth Gordon"},{"id":"758a5b57b56190f64cc434ccb4006a3d","character":"Surfer","name":"Brenda Lowe"},{"id":"40fdce1f64149bf45136ff28025918ad","character":"Huntley Waiter","name":"Pedro Anaya Pérez"},{"id":"58e4f953d2f1253af229313f330e37e1","character":"Pete","name":"Vincenzo Hinckley"},{"id":"aef9ae6d8fc8bf641f10727f4e8bcede","character":"Arian Foster","name":"Arian Foster"},{"id":"306c9a4caca2df0653d80dc56d7c69cf","character":"Pier Mom","name":"Karin Silvestri"},{"id":"5c0d68c7cda1cde707eeb4949d45947a","character":"Baywatch Baby (uncredited)","name":"Tamila Bilalova"},{"id":"3f88083eb7ac451e46aecbbaf7c3ea05","character":"Beach Goer (uncredited)","name":"Casey McCullum"},{"id":"aa467165f29adff4cb79b97339f5ad6b","character":"Lifeguard (uncredited)","name":"Zachary Vazquez"}],"crew":[{"id":"0a6e346c3fb9815eb1cb7ea303d07aff","name":"Seth Gordon","job":"director"}]}}
)
```

Comment: If i change the url to       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.internationalshowtimes.com/v4/cinemas'); I get the error  [code] => 
            [user_message] => Something went wrong.
            [debug_message] => Internal Server Error

Comment: i've edited my answer please check now, you have to add required parameters in order to get the correct result. check each documentation for that

Comment: I am getting the showtime of all the movies but now the parameters like title and the image are not displayed I need that too.

Comment: check the above answer with parameters to be passed with correct location

Comment: I added the above link given by you but still not getting the parameters like title,image

Comment: with movies we can get title and images, check the send URL

Comment: I want all the parameters of showtime as well as the movies

Comment: If you are not getting desired result, then one way is to get show times and using showtimes.movie_id get images, title..

Comment: Can you share the code because I am not understanding what you are talking about

Comment: I am getting the following error- Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded

Comment: because, there are lot of showtimes, 1. you increase maximum_execution_time or 2. reduce the showtimes to many parts

Comment: I got the output but this is only showing me the parameters like title,image,id,slug  it is not showing me showtime parameters like start at,auditorium,booking type.I want both  the parameters of showtime and the movies in the same array

Comment: It will be in showtimes array, you fetch which ever you want in that

Comment: i've added 3 fields, in the same way you can add as many as you want to the array